# Cropping image by selected pixels in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to half the original image by halving height and width of the image and cropping it. [image to be cropped][1]

[image]

and below is my code but it causing a runtime exception and the .exe file stops working with the below error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (rect.width >= 0 && rect.height >= 0 && rect.x < image->width && rect.y < image->height && rect.x + rect.width >= (int)(rect.width > 0) && rect.y + rect.height >= (int)(rect.height > 0)) in cvSetImageROI, file C:\Development\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\array.cpp, line 3006

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.

Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

below is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   IplImage *img1 = cvLoadImage("image/testcase.jpg");
   cvNamedWindow("Image1:",1);
   cvShowImage("Image1:",img1);
   cout << "Width:" <<  img1->width <<" pixels"<< endl;
   cout << "Height:" <<  img1->height <<" pixels"<< endl;
   int width = img1->width ;
   int lenght = img1->height;

   // cropping the image

   Rect roi;
   roi.x = width;
   roi.y = lenght;
   roi.width = (roi.x)/2;
   roi.height = (roi.y)/2;

   Mat image_test;
   image_test = imread("image/testcase");
   // Must have dimensions of output image

   IplImage* cropped = cvCreateImage(cvSize(roi.width,roi.height), img1->depth, img1->nChannels );

   cvSetImageROI(img1, roi);
   cvCopy(img1, cropped);
   cvResetImageROI(img1);
   cvNamedWindow( "Cropped Image", 1 );
   cvShowImage( "Cropped Image", cropped );
   cvSaveImage ("savedImage/cropped.jpg" , cropped);
   waitKey(0);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're using **obsolete** C api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `roi`. Since `x=width` and `y=length`, you're using a roi out of the image. `x` and `y` should be the top-left corner of your roi. In this case they should both be `0`.

You shouldn't use **obsolete** C api.

The get a crop of the top-left part of the image, you can simply:

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Load image
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

    // Define the roi
    Rect roi(0, 0, img.cols / 2, img.rows / 2);

    // Crop
    Mat3b crop = img(roi);

    // Show result
    imshow("Original", img);
    imshow("Crop", crop);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Producing:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Solve d the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using the obsolete API (as pointed out by @Miki), OpenCV is telling you what the problem is (formatted for clarity):

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed 

(rect.width >= 0 
&& rect.height >= 0 
&& rect.x < image->width 
&& rect.y < image->height 
&& rect.x + rect.width >= (int)(rect.width > 0) 
&& rect.y + rect.height >= (int)(rect.height > 0))

in cvSetImageROI, file C:\Development\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\array.cpp, line 3006
```

Specifically, this call to `cvSetImageROI()` is failing:

```
cvSetImageROI(img1, roi);
```

You can determine specifically which of the assertion subconditions are failing by checking each of them via your debugger. You could also print the values out and compare them. Substitute `img1` for `image` and `roi` for `rect`, respectively, i.e.:

```
cout << roi.width << endl; // should be >= 0
cout << roi.height << endl; // should be >= 0
// etc
```